# Angular httpBackend not working with waitsFor and run (expects promise)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tdd, jasmine

Am new to unit testing angular and having a lot of trouble getting my promise and httpBackend to work. The error I'm getting is "timed out after 5000ms waiting for something to happen".

Here's my unit test so far:

```
describe('querySingle', function () {

  var httpBackend;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
  }));

  it('should return the $http promise object when valid', function () {
    httpBackend.expectGet('/rest/report/current/1234123412341234').respond('Hi');
    var request = CurrentRequests.querySingle('1234123412341234');
    var a;

    request.then(function (data) {
      a = data;
    });

    waitsFor(function () {
      return a;
    });

    runs(function () {
      expect(a).toBe('Hi');
    });

  });

  afterEach(function() {
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

});
```

Any advice or help is appreciated, I think my syntax is wrong somewhere, but the angular docs aren't that helpful on this.

Comment: Did you try my solution below ? Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I find that the **[Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/%24httpBackend)** are pretty helpful, clear and detailed !

The waitsFor is for when the data is indeed fetched from the server. But Angular's mocked `$httpBackend` provides the `flush()` method to assist synchronous testing of asynchronous behaviour.

So, your test should look something like this:

```
...
it('should return the $http promise object when valid', function () {
    httpBackend.expectGet('/rest/report/current/1234123412341234').respond('Hi');
    var request = CurrentRequests.querySingle('1234123412341234');
    var a;

    request.then(function (data) {
        a = data;
    });

    httpBackend.flush();
    expect(a).toBe('Hi');
});
...
```